# altFormat not working in jQuery datepicker input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have date field (id begin-date)

```
$( "#begin-date" ).datepicker({ 
  minDate: -20,
  maxDate: "+1M +10D",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altFormat: "yymmdd"
});
```

On post, it prints the format as yy-mm-dd (2010-12-08), when it should print as yymmdd (20101208)

Any ideas of why it is not posting it properly with altFormat set?

input field rendered:

```
<input type="text" name="begin_date" id="begin-date" class="validate[required]" value="" />
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `altFormat` option doesn't control the formatting of the input with the date picker, but the format of an alternate (usually hidden) field specified by [the `altField` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField), like this:

```
$("#begin-date").datepicker({ 
  minDate: -20,
  maxDate: "+1M +10D",
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altFormat: "yymmdd",
  altField: "#alt-date"
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fyv33/11/); what you probably want is to just put the `name` on that alt field and that's what'll get posted...without a `name` the field with the date picker won't get serialized/submitted, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="begin-date" class="validate[required]" />
<input type="text" id="alt-date" name="begin_date" />
```

Comment: @bsreekanth - thanks for letting me know, it looks like the jquery links in that old fiddle no longer pointed to the right place (changes in the fiddle code), I updated the demo to work with a more recent version :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works one way - it will populate the altField, but [it will not initialize correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/7X6v4/) from the value in the altField.

Comment: Here's a [constructor patch](http://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/VpeWQ/) I created to address this - it picks up the value from the altField (respecting the altFormat) and automatically initializes the visible input (respecting the dateFormat).

Comment: lack of hidden input was my problem here

Answer (score 4):

the altFormat must work with altField;

`<input type="text" name="pushTime" class="datetime" id="pushTime"/>
$(".datetime").datepicker({altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",altField: "#pushTime"});`