# Date Output in Rails using jquery ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date-format, date-formatting

I have a form where you click in start_date and a jquery calendar comes up to pick the date.  I want to display the date as (ex.) September 25, 2012, but I also need rails to comprehend the correct start date not just output it correctly.

What do i need to add to this?

```
<%= feed_item.start_date %>
```

events.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $('#event_start_date').datepicker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    $('#event_end_date').datepicker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [altField](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField) and the [altFormat](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) options for the datepicker.

You can store the Rails-friendly date in a hidden field and pass it to the controller, and display the user-friendly field to the user.

**EDIT**

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392097/altformat-not-working-in-jquery-datepicker-input-field) for an example on how to work with altField and altFormat.